# PHP Get result based on the parameter given in the function

Tags: php, functional-programming

I am following Procedural Oriented programming

```
function getTest($p1='', $p2='', $p3='')
{
return ('$p1='.$p1.' : $p2='.$p2.' :  $p3='.$p3);
}
```

Instead of below function call,

```
echo getTest($p1='para 1', '', '');
echo getTest('', $p2='para 2', '');
echo getTest('', $p2='para 2', $p3='para 3');
```

I want to use the below method

```
echo getTest($p1='para 1');
echo getTest($p2='para 2');
echo getTest($p3='para 3');
```

**Current Result**

```
$p1=para 1 : $p2= : $p3=
$p1=para 2 : $p2= : $p3=
$p1=para 3 : $p2= : $p3=
```

**Expected Result**

```
$p1=para 1 : $p2= : $p3=
$p1= : $p2=para 2 : $p3=
$p1= : $p2= : $p3=para 3
```

How can I get the result based on the parameter given?

My objective is that the function should identify the variable name and proceed, rather than proceeding using the parameters order.

Comment: instead of individual values send array of values that available and action accordingly

Answer (score 3):

```
function getTest($args = array())
{
    $arg1 = isset($args['arg1']) ? $args['arg1'] : "";
    $arg2 = isset($args['arg2']) ? $args['arg2'] : "";
    $arg3 = isset($args['arg3']) ? $args['arg3'] : "";

    return ('$p1='.$arg1.' : $p2='.$arg2.' :  $p3='.$arg3);
}

// now simply call function..
$para= array("arg1"=>"para 1",
             "arg2"=>"para 2",
             "arg3"=>"para 3");

$para2= array("arg2"=>"para 2",
              "arg3"=>"para 3");

$para3= array("arg3"=>"para 3");
echo getTest($para);
echo getTest($para2);
echo getTest($para3);
```

Comment: I want something like the function should identify the variable name and proceed.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by passing an array as an argument like the in following example

```
function foo($args)
{
    print "named_arg1 : " . $args["named_arg1"] . "\n";
    print "named_arg2 : " . $args["named_arg2"] . "\n";

 }

foo(array("named_arg1" => "arg1_value", "named_arg2" => "arg2_value"));
```

Php does not support named arguments